# Does datasource access via PROXY or DIRECT have a performance impact?

Tags: grafana

When configuring a datasource, with some datasources like Prometheus I can choose between PROXY access (access via Grafana backend) and DIRECT (access directly from browser). From what I understand PROXY is the recommended option. But it comes with a major downside to me, because now the direct links in the Grafana interface to the Prometheus web UI do not work anymore.

So is there any downside to using the DIRECT option and going via the browser besides stuff around Cross-Origin Resource Sharing? Especially regarding performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROXY access should be slower in theory, because data are going through Grafana backend/proxy.  In real life users won't notice any difference. The best option is to measure it for your use case.

I would prefer PROXY access, because then I can see query errors in the Grafana logs.